# how signed and unsigned integers are stored in c?

Tags: c

I am trying to run the following code but confused with what's happening here:

```
int main()
{
 /* 
    a = -1; 
    b = 0xffffffff; 
 */
if(-1 == 0xffffffff )
        printf("-1 is equal to maximum\n");
else
        printf(" -1 is not equal to maximum\n");

if(0xff < -1)
        printf(" Less than -1 \n");
if(0xff < 0xffffffff)
        printf(" Less than maximum\n");
```

I tried with commented section as well and replaced -1 with "a" and 0xffffffff with "b" but the result is same .

It's 32 bit system so i have taken integer size 4 bytes.

My Output is :

```
-1 is equal to maximum
 Less than maximum
```

If -1 is equal to maximum then it should execute both of the last two if statements. But it's not happening. Why?

Comment: Signed integers are stored in [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation. To represent `-1`: start with `1` (`0x00000001`), perform bit inversion (`0xfffffffe`), add `1` (`0xffffffff`). The most significant bit is always `1` for negative numbers and always `0` for positive numbers. `0xff` is actually `0x000000ff` and is positive and cannot be less than `-1` (`0xffffffff`).

Comment: @HristoIliev ... that's only mandated for `intXX_t`, from `stdint.h`, I thought?

Comment: Actually, C itself does not define how the basic data types are going to be stored. This is dependent upon the implementation.

Comment: @oldrinb: Hristo's statement is more-or-less true, but not guaranteed by the standard. There may be C implementations that aren't 2's complement, but nobody who asks this kind of question will actually encounter one. So it's OK to use 2's complement in your mental model while learning, provided you're aware at some level that other products are available.

Comment: my point is : 1st if shows us that -1 is equal to 0xffffffff so last two should follow the same rule since -1 is same as 0xffffffff last both ifs should be true

Comment: @Omkant: your logic doesn't follow. Because it's converted to unsigned type, -1 is equal to 0xffffffff. When it's not converted to unsigned type, it still behaves like a negative number. Some more tests: `-1 < 0` is true, `-1 == 0xffffffff` is true, but `0xffffffff < 0` is false. -1 and `0xffffffff` are *not* the same number, they just compare equal because of C's rules for comparing signed and unsigned values.

Comment: @SteveJessop that's why I was curious. I know that `intN_t` in `stdint.h` are guaranteed two's complement where implemented by the C standard.

Comment: Then yes, other integer types can be 1s' complement or sign-magnitude. Also other integer types can have padding bits. There's a question somewhere on SO about whether any non-2's-complement implementations exist. Someone came up with a line of mainframes still manufactured surprisingly recently. Anyone who ports existing code to those must *love* their jobs ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll quote this from C++; I think it's the same for C:

The literal `-1` is always a `signed int`.

The literal `0xff` is a `signed int`, but `0xffffffff` is an `unsigned int`.

In comparisons of mixed signs, both operands are converted to unsigned, explaining all your results.

Here's the rule about the types of naked integral literals (i.e. without type suffix) from C++11, table 6:

- Decimal literals are of the smallest type among `int`, `long int` or `long long int`, whichever fits.
- Hexadecimal literals are of the smallest type among `int`, `unsigned int`, `long int`, `unsigned long int`, `long long int`, `unsigned long long int`, whichever fits.

To spell it out again:

- In your first comparison, both sides are converted to `unsigned int`, giving the value `0xFFFFFFFF`.
- In the second comparison, both terms are signed integers, and the left term is `255` and the right term is `-1`.
- In the third comparison, both terms are converted to `unsigned int`.

---

Observe that we never needed to worry about hardware implementations of signedness for this question. The only relevant platform-dependent value is the size of `int`, which we used when we asserted that `0xffffffff` does not fit into an `int` but *does* fit into an `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 3):

In C/C++, negative numbers are stored in 2's compliment format and Most Significant Bit(MSB) acts as a sigh indication.

MSB 1 means -ve and MSB 0 means +ve. 
1xxxxxxxxxx is -ve number and 0xxxxxxxxxx means +ve. 
In 1xxxxxxx the "xxxxxx" is 2's compliment of a number.
And in 0xxxxxx the "xxxxx" is actual binary representation of a number.

Compiler interpret number as -ve if MSB(sign bit) is 1 and understands the number has to be the two's compliment.

First lets see what is 2's compliment:

2's compliment is negating an actual number(all bits) and then adding 1.

decimal 1 = 00000001

~ decimal 1 = 11111110

2's compliment of decimal 1 = 11111111 (F hex)

so -1 becomes = **(1)** 111111111111111

**(1)** is a MSB indicating -ve number the rest is the 2's compliment of a number.

thus -1 = 0xFFFFFFFF

You can try out printing binary representation of some -ve numbers and comparing the 2's compliment of binary representation of a number.

Answer (score 0):

`0xffffffff` is equal to `-1` since the `int` type has only four bytes and the [two-complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) of `-1` is `0xffffffff` in memory (`-1 == (~1) + 1`). So the compiler has no way to tell `-1` and `0xffffffff` apart - there simply isn't room for that in memory.

`0x000000ff` is equivalent to `255` which is bigger than `-1`, so the last two `if`s won't get executed.

What might be confusing you is this:

```
char c = 0xff;
if( c == -1 ) {
     printf("char 0xff is -1");
}
```

In this case, I compare a `char` with an `int`, so the compiler will have to expand the 8-bit `char` type. Since `char` is signed, the sign (uppermost bit) will be preserved and you'll get `-1` (int).

[interactive demo on codepad](http://codepad.org/hbybmSKP)

This is an example why you need to be careful when mixing signed/unsigned types and types of different widths.

Comment: yeah, It means when we compare any negative integer with any other data type it takes the size of that datatype and then converted to 2's complement.. Because here when compare with char ,they became equal ?

Answer (score 0):

First thing, the results you see have *nothing to do with the bit representation of signed integers*, although they do have to do with the size.

When converted to unsigned, the value `-1` is converted to the max value of the destination type. That's why `-1 == 0xffffffff`. The bit representation of `-1` doesn't affect anything.

`0xff < -1` is false because both values are signed `int`: 255 on the left and -1 on the right.

Finally, the reason -1 is converted to unsigned in the first comparison is that `0xffffffff` is too big for `int` *on your implementation* (and for that matter on most implementations). However, it does fit in an `unsigned int` (again on your implementation, and on most implementations other than those for 16 bit machines). In order to compare an unsigned int against a signed int, C converts the signed int to unsigned. This gives surprising results (including the surprise that -1 is somehow equal to a positive number), which is why most style guides tell you to avoid mixing signed and unsigned types. But it's too late to change the language.